# Segmentation fault error while Input value to array in a structured array

Tags: c, arrays, input

I have a problem with the structure of C. I want to write a program which reads data from`grades.txt` , save it to the structured array and print it. So I wrote a code below this.
**program.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("grades.txt","r");
    int i = 0,j;
    typedef struct
    {
        int number;
        int q[4];
        int total;
    } student;
    student a[101];
    while(feof(fp1) == 0)
    {
        if(i==0) i++;
        else
        {
            fscanf(fp1,"%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a[i].number, &a[i].q[0], &a[i].q[1], &a[i].q[2], &a[i].q[3], &a[i].total);
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a[i].number,a[i].q[0], a[i].q[1], a[i].q[2], a[i].total);
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it prints garbage values and segmentation fault error.

```
778121006 7632239 778121006 7632239 0 -1399308296
Segmentation fault
```

And the content of grades.txt is

**grades.txt**

```
ID       Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Total
20131122 20 14 18 22    74
20132400 16 23 11 19    69
```

Comment: See: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/253056). Also you need to add error checking after your call to `fopen`.

Comment: What Paul R writes. Also, you forget to skip the first line, which contains text, rather than numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you didn't check the return value of `fopen()` as if file doesn't exist your code shouldn't do further operation on `fp1`. So check the return value as

```
fp1 = fopen("grades.txt","r");
if(fp1 == NULL) {
   /* error handling */
}
```

Secondly, as mentioned by @paul [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) , instead use `fscanf()` inside `while` loop & check the return value of `fscanf()` as

```
while(fscanf(fp1,"%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a[i].number, &a[i].q[0], &a[i].q[1], &a[i].q[2], &a[i].q[3], &a[i].total) == 6 ) { /* 6 is the no of read item */
      printf("%d %d %d %d %d \n", a[i].number,a[i].q[0], a[i].q[1], a[i].q[2], a[i].total);
      i++; 
}
```

Some silly mistakes you did as there was one extra `%d` inside `printf()` statement that you could have solved or observed while compiling with `-Wall` flag.
This

```
printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a[i].number,a[i].q[0], a[i].q[1], a[i].q[2], a[i].total);
```

having six `%d` but you provided only 5 argument, remove extra `%d` as there are only 5 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to skip the first line. You increment i, but you dont skip the first line. You make the program read characters as ints.
Perhaps something along the lines of

```
fscanf(fp1,"%s %s %s %s %s %s", ....(strings here) );
```

in the if block